# How to convert decorator method to a class in python

Tags: python

I have a class that contains an inner class containing decorators. For example

```
class MyClass():

    class Decorators():

        @classmethod
        def dekarait(cls, func):

            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(cls, name: str, count: int = 0):
                print(name * count)
                func()

            return wrapper

    def __init__(self) -> None:

    @Decorators.dekarait
    def good(self, name: str, count: int = 0) -> str:

        out:str = f"name:{name}"
        print("hello")
        return out
```

This works as intended. However, I would like to get rid of the inner `Decorators` class and convert the class method `dekarait` into a class of it's own.

I have tried

```
class MyClass():

    class Dekarait():

        def __init__(self, func):

            self.func = func

        def __call__(self, func):
            def wrapper(self, name: str, count: int = 0):
                print(name * count)
                func()

            return wrapper

    def __init__(self) -> None:

    @Dekarait
    def good(self, name: str, count: int = 0) -> str:

        out:str = f"name:{name}"
        print("hello")
        return out
```

I am stuck at this point. I get errors for missing arguments `name` and `count` for `__call___` but when I add them I still get errors.

I would be grateful if someone can talk me through what to change and why.

Comment: "However, I would like to ... convert the class method dekarait into a class of it's own" - why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to define another wrapper function inside the `__call__` method because the `__call__` method itself can be a wrapper of the decorator function already:

```
class MyClass():
    class Dekarait():
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func

        def __call__(self, name: str, count: int = 0):
            print(name * count)
            return self.func(name, count)

    @Dekarait
    def good(self, name: str, count: int = 0) -> str:
        out:str = f"name:{name}"
        print("hello")
        return out

print(MyClass.good('hi', 2))
```

This outputs:

```
hihi
hello
name:2
```